# Finding duplicates from column in the rest of database with JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpql

I've got few columns in my db. I want to choose one and then return all of the records where values are duplicated. So I want to like, get one column and check which values from my column appeared from the rest of the db. Then return this records. Let's say that database looks like this:

```sql
id;col1;col2;col3;col4

'1','ab','cd','ef','1'
'2','ad','bg','ee','5'
'3','xx','bg','cc','6'
'4','vv','zz','ff','4'
'5','zz','ee','gg','4'
'6','zz','vv','zz','2'
'7','vv','aa','bb','8'
'8','ww','nn','zz','4'
'9','zz','yy','ff','9'
'10','qq','oo','ii','3'
```

and I want my result for col1 to look like so

```
4,'vv','zz','ff',4
5,'zz','ee','gg',4
6,'zz','vv','zz',2
7,'vv','aa','bb',8
9,'zz','yy','ff',9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we present the duplicates in 2 different ways. The first is the format you have requested, with additional information. The second is more concise.

> ```
> create table t1(
> id varchar(10),
> col1 varchar(10),
> col2 varchar(10),
> col3 varchar(10),
> col4 varchar(10));
> ```

> ```
> insert into t1 values
> ('1','ab','cd','ef','1'),
> ('2','ad','bg','ee','5'),
> ('3','xx','bg','cc','6'),
> ('4','vv','zz','ff','4'),
> ('5','zz','ee','gg','4'),
> ('6','zz','vv','zz','2'),
> ('7','vv','aa','bb','8'),
> ('8','ww','nn','zz','4'),
> ('9','zz','yy','ff','9'),
> ('10','qq','oo','ii','3');
> ```

> ```
> select * from t1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
> :- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :---
> 1  | ab   | cd   | ef   | 1   
> 2  | ad   | bg   | ee   | 5   
> 3  | xx   | bg   | cc   | 6   
> 4  | vv   | zz   | ff   | 4   
> 5  | zz   | ee   | gg   | 4   
> 6  | zz   | vv   | zz   | 2   
> 7  | vv   | aa   | bb   | 8   
> 8  | ww   | nn   | zz   | 4   
> 9  | zz   | yy   | ff   | 9   
> 10 | qq   | oo   | ii   | 3
> ```

> ```
> with cte as(
> select
>   id,
>   col1,
>   col2,
>   col3,
>   col4,
>   row_number() over 
>     ( partition by col1
>       order by id desc) r1,
> row_number() over 
>     ( partition by col2
>       order by id desc) r2,
> row_number() over 
>     ( partition by col3
>       order by id desc) r3,
> row_number() over 
>     ( partition by col4
>       order by id desc) r4
> from t1 
>  )
> select * 
> from cte
> where
> r1 > 1
> or r2 > 1
> or r3 > 1
> or r4 > 1;
> ```

> ```
> id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | r1 | r2 | r3 | r4
> :- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | -: | -: | -: | -:
> 6  | zz   | vv   | zz   | 2    |  2 |  1 |  2 |  1
> 5  | zz   | ee   | gg   | 4    |  3 |  1 |  1 |  2
> 4  | vv   | zz   | ff   | 4    |  2 |  1 |  2 |  3
> 2  | ad   | bg   | ee   | 5    |  1 |  2 |  1 |  1
> ```

> ```
> select 'col1' as "column",
>    col1 "value", 
>    count(id) "count"
> from t1 group by col1
> having count(id)>1
> union all
> select 'col2',col2, count(id)
> from t1 group by col2
> having count(id)>1
> union all
> select 'col3',col3, count(id)
> from t1 group by col3
> having count(id)>1
> union all
> select 'col4',col4, count(id)
> from t1 group by col4
> having count(id)>1
> order by "column","value";
> ```

> ```
> column | value | count
> :----- | :---- | ----:
> col1   | vv    |     2
> col1   | zz    |     3
> col2   | bg    |     2
> col3   | ff    |     2
> col3   | zz    |     2
> col4   | 4     |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80ccc10f712b5a61ed592bf98770cbec)*